# Python 3 syntax error with def function((x,y))

Tags: python, function, parameters, python-3.x, python-2.x

So I'm analyzing this code and I have reason to believe this was coded with python 2.X but I'm using 3.2 and would like to convert it so that it would work.

The first error I encountered was with a function with a syntax

```
def function((x,y))
```

Why doesn't it work in Py3 and what's the alternative?

Comment: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Mr E already said in the comment, this feature was removed in Python 3 with [PEP 3113](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/). The alternative is very simple, you just have a single parameter which you unpack manually:

```
def func (xy):
    x, y = xy
    # ...
```

Or you define the function with two parameters, and make users of the function unpack their values themselves:

```
def func (x, y):
    # ...

t = (1, 2)
func(*t)
```

Btw. it’s a good idea to run Python’s `2to3` tool to convert existing Python 2 code to match Python 3’s syntax and library changes.

Answer (score 1):

[2to3](http://svn.python.org/view/sandbox/trunk/2to3/fixes/fix_tuple_params.py) will, in theory, take care of this for you. I say "in theory" because I have not used it, but most of Python works as advertised.